# Angular 5 dentro de iframe en página aspx

Tags: angular, iframe, angular5

Estoy creando una aplicación en Angular 5. Esta aplicación es llamada desde una página aspx por medio de un iframe pero la aplicación simplemente no aparece.
Este es el código de mi página aspx que llama a mi aplicación Angular por medio de un iframe:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <iframe src="https://localhost:4200" width="100%" height="auto"></iframe>
</div>
</form>
```

Adjunto imagen de como se ve el iframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué ocurre si usas esa misma url directamente? ¿se carga la aplicación?

Comment: no entendí muy bien tu propuesta, pero si coloco "..localhost:4200.." en el navegador, carga mi aplicación angular % sin problemas, también probé haciendo un redirect, y mi aplicación angular 5 carga bien pero el problema es que esa aplicación angular es parte de un menú. y al hacer el redirect el menú se pierde, por eso utilizo el iframe , para cargar la aplicación angular dentro de la pagina y dentro del menú, pero la aplicación no se ve.

Comment: Aparece algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: nop, la consola esta mas limpia que el alma de Jesus.

Comment: Es extraño, los iframes pueden no ser cargados si el padre es http y el hijo no lo es, o los puertos o servidores desde donde se cargan son diferentes a los de la página padre, pero en esos casos se suele ver un aviso en la consola del navegador